# Ionic 2 camera plugin Installation error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to install ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
and getting following error in windows system-

Ionic cordova -plugin installation error

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-camera via registry. Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output: node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs' node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Module.require (module.js:498:17) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at require (internal/module.js:20:19) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at evalmachine.<anonymous>:18:20 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\thread-sleep\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\nod e_modules\tar\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Module.load (module.js:488:32) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Ionic Demo\\Social-Media\\node_modules\\thread-sleep\\node_modul es\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\thread-sleep node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v7.5.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.9 node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`. node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help: node-pre-gyp ERR! <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: thread-sleep@1.0.4 (node_modules\thread-sleep): npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: thread-sleep@1.0.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 7 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordov a-plugin-camera" "--save" npm ERR! node v7.5.0 npm ERR! npm v4.1.2 npm ERR! path D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\thread-sleep\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\node_modules\nopt\node_modules npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall scandir npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\thread-sleep\node_modules\node-pre-g yp\node_modules\nopt\node_modules' npm ERR! { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\thread-sleep\node_modules\node-pr e-gyp\node_modules\nopt\node_modules' npm ERR! errno: -4048, npm ERR! code: 'EPERM', npm ERR! syscall: 'scandir', npm ERR! path: 'D:\\Ionic Demo\\Social-Media\\node_modules\\thread-sleep\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\node_modules\\nopt\\node_modu les' } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator. npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR! D:\Ionic Demo\Social-Media\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Any help in this would be appreciable,thanks

Comment: what is `ionic info` output?

Comment: ordova CLI: 7.0.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: I am also new for Ionic-2 and I am facing the same problem. I am able to install the plugin but not able to find ionic/native for Camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this reinstalling the plugin for backwards compatible with previous versions of Cordova `cordova-plugin-compat`.

You have to follow this steps:

> cordova plugin remove --force cordova-plugin-compat
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera